# Can I use reactJS library in react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

Well, this might be a silly question but I want to clarify the reason.
React-Native imports nodeJS libraries, so I think it is possible to use reactJS library as well though reactJS includes pure html components.

Can react native recognize reactJS components including html?

Comment: React-native is written in React + platform bindings. So obviously you are using React underneath in React-Native

Comment: So you mean I can use any reactJS library in react native?

Comment: Yes, correct, visit official react-native website, __Build native mobile apps using JavaScript and React__

Comment: No you can't. react-native uses react underneath but you can't use pure HTML elements in react-native. This is why you need to implement react-native version of that library. Especially when its a visual component. If there are no visual components then you might be able to use the library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`react` library actually does not have anything related to Browser DOM HTML. Anything related to it separated into `react-dom` package. React Native does not and cannot use this library, because you don't have DOM underneath a react native application. However you can use most of the code/functionality you wrote for your mobile app in the browser, if you install necessary transpiling library. This is possible because react native defines some primitive components that can be ported to almost any platform.
If you still want to use just HTML to render inside react native, you may use [`WebView`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually libraries built specifically for other platforms will not work with React Native. Examples include react-select which is built for the web and specifically targets react-dom, and rimraf which is built for Node.js and interacts with your computer file system. Other libraries like lodash use only JavaScript language features and work in any environment. You will gain a sense for this over time, but until then the easiest way to find out is to try it yourself. You can remove packages using npm uninstall if it turns out that it does not work in React Native.
-- source: React native official docs