# Validator for password not working on react native

Tags: react-native, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on latest `react-native` version.
I'm trying to implement a `custom validator` to check if the `password` and `password` confirm are `equal`. The problem is that the validator function is not working.

**Library Link**  [react-reactive-form](https://github.com/bietkul/react-reactive-form)

**Code**

```
MatchPassword(AC: AbstractControl) {
  let password = AC.get('new_password').value; // to get value in input tag
  let confirmPassword = AC.get('confirm_password').value; // to get value in input tag
  if (password !== confirmPassword) {
    AC.get('confirm_password').setErrors({ mismatch: true });
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

changePasswordForm = FormBuilder.group({
  new_password: ['', [Validators.required]],
  confirm_password: ['', [Validators.required]],
}, {
  validator: this.MatchPassword,
});

render() {
return (
    <Fragment>
        <FieldGroup
            control={this.changePasswordForm}
            render={() => {
                return (
                    <Fragment>
                        <FieldControl
                            name="new_password"
                            render={({ handler, touched, hasError, ...props }) => (
                                <Fragment>
                                    <TextInput {...props} label="New Password" placeholder="Password" handler={handler} type="password" secureTextEntry  />
                                    {(touched && hasError('required')) && <ErrorText message="This Field Should Not Be Empty." />}
                                </Fragment>
                            )}
                        />
                        <FieldControl
                            name="confirm_password"
                            render={({ handler, touched, hasError, ...props }) => (
                                <Fragment>
                                    <TextInput {...props} label="Confirm Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" handler={handler} type="password" secureTextEntry />
                                    {(touched && hasError('required')) && <ErrorText message="This Field Should Not Be Empty." />}
                                    {(touched && hasError('mismatch')) && <ErrorText message="Password No Match!" />}
                                </Fragment>
                            )}
                        />

                        <Button onPress={() => this.handleSubmit()} variant="success" block large style={[mb0, mr15, flex1]}>Submit</Button>
                    </Fragment>
                );
            }}
        />
    </Fragment>
);
}
```

Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have used the react JS packages to validate the form. React JS packages can't be used for react-native projects. You should check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123840/can-i-use-reactjs-library-in-react-native)

Abstract of your problem:

react library actually does not have anything related to Browser DOM HTML. Anything related to it separated into react-dom package. React Native does not and cannot use this library, because you don't have DOM underneath a react native application. However you can use most of the code/functionality you wrote for your mobile app in the browser

You can validate your form using these packages:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-form-validator

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-validator-form

https://github.com/jeffraux/react-native-validate-form